# How to add a dynamic Wordpress menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an online store on WordPress.
I periodically import products with XML there using the WP All Import plugin.

I have categories and subcategories displayed in the menu.

I add items to the menu when new categories appear when uploading.

How do I automate this process?
Make it so that when uploading all new subcategories and categories are automatically added to the menu?

Comment: You can try using this method https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99312/199756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code was perfect for me, thank you!

```
$prod_cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy'    => 'product_cat',
    'orderby'     => 'id', 
    'hide_empty'  => false, 
    'parent'      => 0 
  );

$woo_categories = get_categories( $prod_cat_args );
  foreach ( $woo_categories as $woo_cat ) {
      $woo_cat_id = $woo_cat->term_id; //category ID
      $woo_cat_name = $woo_cat->name; //category name
      $woo_cat_slug = $woo_cat->slug; //category slug
      echo '<div class="main-cat-item">';
      $category_thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($woo_cat_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
      $thumbnail_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail_id);
      echo '<img src="' . $thumbnail_image_url . '"/>';
      echo '<h2>';
      echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $woo_cat_id, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $woo_cat_name . '</a>;
      echo '</h2>';
      echo "</div>\n";
  }
```